# Probability game with two players

Tags: probability

There are two players A and B. 
Player A has $(n+1)$ fair coins, and player B has $n$ fair coins.
$n$ is a positive integer $(n>=1)$. 
Both players toss all coins they have, if B has at least many heads as A then B win.

What is the probability that B wins ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Partition the results.  $A$ has one more coin than $B$, which is an extra head once every two tries.

Let $A_k, B_k$ be the amount of heads among the first $k$ tosses for the respective players.   Then, by the Law of Total Probability, we assert:
$$\mathsf P(B_n\geq A_{n+1}) = \tfrac 12\mathsf P(B_n>A_n)+\tfrac 12\mathsf P(B_n\geq A_n)$$

---

Hint: Calculate $\mathsf P(B_n=A_n)$ and argue from symmetry.

Hint 2: $\sum_{k=0}^r \binom {n} {k} \binom {m}{r-k} = \binom{m+n}r$ is a somewhat well known identity (Vandermonde's).

Answer (score 1):

Let us pause when both have tossed $n$ coins.

To win, B must either be ahead at this stage (with probability $p$, say) or tied, and *remain tied*.
By symmetry, P(A is ahead) is also $p$, and thus P(tie at **this** stage) $=1-2p$.

Thus P(B eventually wins) $= p + \frac12(1-2p) = \frac12$